# Media Queries not changing according to size , always showing blue background

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive, background-color

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Mobile Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F09A9D;
    /* Red */
  }
}


/* Tablet Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-color: #F5CF8E;
    /* Yellow */
  }
}


/* Desktop Styles */

@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
  body {
    background-color: #B2D6FF;
    /* Blue */
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot replicate

Comment: It's working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h1su2je8/)

Comment: i checked on chrome dev tools , it's working after adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please add this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in your header, in order to let the browser know the scale on which the media queries will be evaluated

Comment: I really want to know who downvote... however, mark this as answer, and in order to improve the community, leave an upvote on each answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

you have to put

at you index.html file in  tag like this

```
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

</body>


</html>
```